# Como manipular css com Vue

Tags: css3, vue.js

Tenho uma dúvida, desejo manipular o **css** do elemento **body**(mais especificamente o font-size) usando **Vue.js** só que eu não acho uma maneira de fazer isto. O que desejo é que quando eu apertar o botão ele use um método que aumente o valor do font-size.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />

    <button @click="aumentaFont()" class="button">Aumenta Fonte</button>

    <section class="l100">
      <nuxt />
    </section>

    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<style>
html,
body {
  font-size: 1em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Então Matheus, você olhou a documentação oficial antes de criar a pergunta? Tem uma [sessão](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Interligando-Estilos-Inline) explicando sobre isso.

Comment: Okay, mas não vejo onde posso inserir esses dados no body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos la, minha recomendação é criar classes de estilo que quer aplicar no body para os devidos tamanho de `font-size`.

Ai no seu componente Vue você faz a lógica para aplicar as classes no body de forma dinâmica, exemplo:

No seu assets/css/main.css:

```
.small-font-size {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.medium-font-size {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.large-font-size {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

> Carrega esse .css no seu projeto, não precisa estar associado a nenhum componente.

Ai no seu componente responsável por mudar o tamanho da fonte:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="smaller" :disabled="isSmallest">Diminuir fonte</button>
    <button type="button" @click="bigger" :disabled="isBiggest">Aumentar fonte</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'FontSizeController',
  data() {
    return {
      fontSize: 2 // vamos dizer que 2 é medium, 1 é small e 3 é large
    };
  },
  computed: {
     isSmallest({ fontSize }) {
       return fontSize == 1;
     }
     isBiggest({ fontSize }) {
       return fontSize == 3;
     }
  },
  methods: {
    smaller() {
      if (this.fontSize > 1) {
        this.fontSize--;
        this.updateBodyFontSize();
      }
    },
    bigger() {
      if (this.fontSize < 3) {
        this.fontSize++;
        this.updateBodyFontSize();
      }
    },
    updateBodyFontSize() {
      const body = document.querySelector('body');

      switch (this.fontSize) {
        case 1:
          body.classList.add('small-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('medium-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('large-font-size');
          break;
        case 2:
          body.classList.add('medium-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('small-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('large-font-size');
          break;
        case 3:
          body.classList.add('large-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('medium-font-size');
          body.classList.remove('small-font-size');
          break;
      }
    },        
  }
}
</script>
```